# How to figure out the magnets needed to repulse a given weight?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, levitation

Given a weight. Is it possible to determine what strength of magnet and what width, length and thickness would be needed in order to repulse that weight a given height? If so, how?

To be clear:

Two magnets, one on top of the other, repulsing.

||=========||
^^^^air^^^^
||=========||

Now I'll place an object of a certain weight on top.

I want the object to float in mid air at a certain height.

I am trying to figure out how to calculate what strength magnet I'd need in order to make the object float at a given height, given a weight of said object. Pick any type of magnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Given a weight

Knowing the weight is not enough.  Each material has its own [magnetic susceptibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_susceptibility), which can even be a tensor for a crystal.  We would need to know the weight and the magnetic susceptiblity to know how the material would behave in a given magnetic field.

For example [diamagnetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism) materials experience a force in a direction of decreasing field strength, while [paramagnetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramagnetic) materials experience a force in a direction of increasing field strength.

> Is it possible to determine what strength of magnet

It is not just a matter of the strength of magnetic field.  The gradient of the magnetic field matters.

---

For the edited version of the question asking about the [force between two magnets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets), Wikipedia has equations for various shapes of magnets at the above link. The force from those equations must exceed the gravitational force (weight) for levitation.

Comment: I edited my question above for clarification.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets